# Strapi v4: middleware from plugin

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have created plugin, for example `TagsPlugin`. The main idea that plugin for example add `Tags` for any `content-type`. I need create middleware to add `Tags` to each request if they are exists for current `content-type`

I create Middleware in `my-plugin-folder/server/middlewares/tags.ts`
what looks like

```
/**
 * `tags` middleware
 */

import { Strapi } from '@strapi/strapi';

const tags = (config, { strapi }: { strapi: Strapi }) => {
  // Add your own logic here.
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    strapi.log.info('In tags middleware.');
    console.log('TAGS MIDDLEWARE');

    await next();
  };
};

export default tags;
```

And in `my-plugin-folder/server/register.ts` depending on documentation i've add `strapi.server.use(middlewares.tags);` - in this case all app don't work without any error.
I need to add this middleware globally, but i cant find info how to do that. alsoo i tried add `strapi.middleware('plugin::plugin-name.middleware-name');` to /my-app/config/middleares.ts` but its also get me an error.

What the correct way to add global middleware from plugin instead creating app-level middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this document:
https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/plugins/server-api#middlewares

**plugin-folder/server/middlewares/tags.ts**

```
'use strict';
const tags = async (ctx, next) => {
  strapi.log.info(`tags: ${ctx.method} ${ctx.originalUrl} ${ctx.status} - ${ctx.headers['host']}`);

  await next();
};
export default tags;
```

=> the export parameters of plugin middleware is different to application's middleware

**plugin-folder/server/register.ts**

```
import {Strapi} from '@strapi/strapi';

import tagsMiddleware from './middlewares/tags';

export default ({strapi}: {strapi: Strapi}) => {
  // register phase
  strapi.server.use(tagsMiddleware);
  // or
  /*
  strapi.server.use(async (ctx: any, next: any) => {
    strapi.log.info(`tags: ${ctx.method} ${ctx.originalUrl} ${ctx.status} - ${ctx.headers['host']}`);

    await next();
  });
  */
};
```